# Cocos2d-x with parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, cocos2d-x

I would like to create an Android app with Cocos2d-x that uses Parse.com as its backend. From what I have researched so far, it looks like C++ is the language that I will be creating the app in. Is this correct?

I have created a 'Hello World' Cocos2d-x app, but I'm confused about adding the SDK. When I go to Parse.com and look for an SDK I only see the option to go with Native (java) or Xamarin (C#). Is there a C++ SDK that I am overlooking? Am I approaching this the wrong way or is there a way to use the Native SDK when writing the app in C++? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Parse SDK for cocos2dx, C++. If you want to use parse as backend in your game, you have to understand about EasyNDK, and how to use it well. By the way, if you uses as backend, you have to write code in every platform.

Comment: Moreover, if you don't want to use EasyNDK, you can use RESTful API of Parse.com and you don't have to write code for every platform.